# when i am trying to write file each chunk from thread its getting overwritten

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Hi I have data stored in chunk  of n number of threads. the size of file is 102kb, so I am trying to lock the shared resource i.e. the file and then when I write the first chunk i release the lock, but when it comes for the next chink from the second thread, instead of file to continue from where it left it starts to write the chunk on top if it...

so the 102 kb file becomes 51 for two threads each having chunk of 51kb

here is the piece of code.

```
for th in threads:
    th.join()

for th in threads:
    lock.acquire()
    with open(fileName, 'w+') as fh:
        fh.write(th.data)
    lock.release()
```

I am even using mode `w+` still instead of appending its overwriting..

**update**

```
def main(url=None, splitBy=2):
    start_time = time.time()
    if not url:
        print "Please Enter some url to begin download."
        return

    fileName = url.split('/')[-1]
    sizeInBytes = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None)
    # if os.path.exists(fileName):
    #   if int(sizeInBytes) == os.path.getsize(fileName):
    #       raise SystemExit("File already exists.")

    print "%s bytes to download." % sizeInBytes
    if not sizeInBytes:
        print "Size cannot be determined."
        return
    threads = []
    lock = threading.Lock()

    byteRanges = buildRange(int(sizeInBytes), splitBy)
    for idx in range(splitBy):
        bufTh = SplitBufferThread(url, byteRanges[idx])
        bufTh.daemon = True
        bufTh.start()
        threads.append(bufTh)
    print "--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time)


    for i, th in enumerate(threads):
        th.join()
        lock.acquire()


        with open(fileName, 'a') as fh:
            fh.write(th.data)
            if i == len(threads) - 1:
                fh.seek(0, 0)
                fh.flush()
        lock.release()
```

**Update 2**

I have totally removed the extra threads list, just using the `join()` method does the magic , but how does the thread wait for one chunk to finish writing is it using `with` waits for one thread.data to be written and then next one gets to start appending **??**

```
 def main(url=None, splitBy=6):
    if not url:
        print "Please Enter some url to begin download."
        return

    fileName = url.split('/')[-1]
    sizeInBytes = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None)
    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        if int(sizeInBytes) == os.path.getsize(fileName):
            ask = raw_input('[YES]')
            if not ask or ask.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
                os.remove(fileName)
            else:
                raise SystemExit("File already exists.")

    start_time = time.time()
    print "%s bytes to download." % sizeInBytes
    if not sizeInBytes:
        print "Size cannot be determined."
        return

    byteRanges = buildRange(int(sizeInBytes), splitBy)
    for idx in range(splitBy):
        bufTh = SplitBufferThread(url, byteRanges[idx])
        bufTh.daemon = True
        bufTh.start()
        with open(fileName, 'a+') as fh:
            bufTh.join()
            fh.write(bufTh.data)

    print "--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time)


    print "Finished Writing file %s" % fileName
```

Comment: Try changing the mode to "a" instead of "w+". "w+" does not append to the file, but overwrites it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w

Comment: sorry first mistake was using `w+` but even if I try with `a` it continues appending the file , so i tried to set `fh.seek(0, 0)` but it didn't work it continues to append bytes

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to achieve? Do you want it to append to the file or overwrite it?

Comment: append. but once all the chunks are appended I want to set the pointer to beginning, so that the on restarting to download the same file should not append instead start from the beginning.

Comment: @ColinAtkinson I have posted an update. but I want to completely bypass storing chunks to list... instead use the first loop where i start the thread to use to write the file to disk as soon as thread finishes it's chunk.

Comment: So, you seek(0,0) and wonder why file keeps getting overwritten? Notice, in your for loop, you are in a single thread and there is no reason obtain a lock or open the file multiple times. Just open the file before the for loop and write the results of each thread.

Comment: removed lock after downloading the file , if i redownload it the file only gets appended.

Comment: Setting the file pointer position at the end is pointless; it only persists as long as you have that file open. The easiest way to do what you are requesting is to clear the file when it is first opened. This will remove the old data, and you will then be free to write your new content to.

Comment: so because I am using `with` after `fh.write` is done is it pointless to `fh.seek` after `fh.write` if I do not use the with instead would that make sense ? however `os.remove` if file exist on disk does make sense.

Comment: The position of the file pointer does not persist between sessions. So, once the program exits, regardless of how you open the file, the pointer will be reset when the file is opened again. You can use `os.remove`, but my personal recommendation would be to open the file as "w" and close it, which will empty it. Then, like you did in the update, open it with "a" and write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

``w+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
         the beginning of the file.

try with "a+"

Comment: "r+" still opens the file to be read/written to instead of appended

Comment: then "a+"? I thought you want to seek the correct position in the file.

Comment: "a" opens the file for appending, meaning the file pointer is at the end of the file. "a+" just means that the file can also be read.

Comment: I think you should explain better what you want to achieve. I don't understand...

Comment: He just wants to write  the file. That's what 'a' is for.