# mailgun send inline image not working?

Tags: python, mailgun, inline-images

I use mailgun to send mail.
I try to use python api

```
pwd = "path-to-image/logo.png"
return requests.post(
     "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/sandboxsomething.mailgun.org/messages",
     auth=("api", "key-something"),
     files=[("inline", open(pwd)),],
     data={"from": src,
           "to": des,
           "subject": sub,
           "html": message})
```

but It can't send image.

after that I try to show just png file when I print `print open(pwd).read()` I get:

```
 �PNG


 none
```

but when I try to `print open('path-to-image/a.txt')`,I get content the file:

```
all content of a.text
none
```

why the `png` file not read?

Comment: What does "it can'd send image" mean? Does it produce an error message? Does the mail not get sent? Does the mail get sent, but has the wrong data?

Comment: It send message, but the image can not be show,because It's empty!. I try to print image before send it,and I get `�PNG   none`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open for image must be:

```
open(pwd,"rb")
```

for read it in binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
open(pwd,"rb")
```

you can use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566951/3726821

Answer (score 1):

A little late to answer this but i was also looking for a solution and could not find any online. I have coded my own and i taught i share it here.

When mailgun post a new message to an endpoint, it parses inline images as attachments. Here is a fix to keep the images inline using PHP.

```
//Handling images
if(!empty($_FILES)){

   //Remove <> from string to set proper array key
   $inline_images=str_replace(array('<', '>'), '', $_POST['content-id-map']);

   //Get inline images
   $inline_images=json_decode($inline_images, true);

   if(!empty($inline_images)){

       foreach($inline_images as $key=>$i){
          if(isset($_FILES[$i])){

             //Now we have the inline images. You upload it to a folder or encode it base64.

            //Here is an example using base64
            $image=file_get_contents(base64_encode($_FILES[$i]['tmp_name']));

            //Now, we will str_replace the image from the email body with the encoded 6ase64 image. 

           $_POST['body-html']=str_replace('cid:'.$key, 'data:image/png;base64,'.$image, $_POST['body-html']);
        }
  }


   //Parsing actual attachments

      //Unset all inline images from attachments array
      foreach($inline_images as $i){
         unset($_FILES[$i]);
      }

       //Now, since we have removed all inline images from $_FILES. You can add your code to parse actual attachments here. 
   }
}
```

There you go, an easy way to parse inline attachments using mailgun.