# ConfigParser overwriting the content of config file

Tags: python, python-2.7, overwrite, configparser

I am having a problem when writing to a config file. I have two Python scripts that read and write to the same file. the problem is when I write to it from one script it overwrites the content from the other script.

Here is my code:

```
authfile = "Users/.ahs" # .ahs is a hidden file
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
tmpfile = open(authfile, "w+")
config.add_section(s)
config.set(s, k, t)
config.write(tmpfile)
tmpfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w+` truncates the file when it opens, are you sure you didn't mean `a` or `a+`?

See [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)