# Unsure of the behavior for opening a file with mode "wrb"

Tags: python, sockets, file-io

I have a socket that I am sending data to through a file created using the makefile method of a socket.  However, the mode of the file created using makefile is 'wrb'.

I understand that 'w' = write, 'r' = read, and 'b' = binary.  I also understand that you can combine them in a number of different ways, see [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w), which contains a list of possible combinations.  However, I've never seen 'w' and 'r' together.

What is their behavior when together?  For example, 'r+' allows reading and writing, and 'w+' does the same, except that it truncates the file beforehand.  But what does 'wr' do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description in the [Python 2.x docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open%20'Documentation') suggests you would be able to both read and write to the file without closing it.

However, the behavior is not so.

Example:

```
f = open('myfile', 'wr')
f.write('THIS IS A TEST')
f.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

It will write, however not read. If we open the file with the option reversed:

```
f = open('myfile', 'rw')
f.read()
f.write('THIS IS ALSO A TEST')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Observed behavior is that the open() function only takes the first character for file opening  option, and disregards the rest except if it ends in a 'b', which would donate that it would be opened in binary mode.

Comment: I was able to duplicate the results that you posted on codingground, which looks like it's running Python 2.7.5 on Fedora 20; however, I was not able to do so on my personal work machine.  Here I'm running Python 2.7.1 on Win7 and receiving a ValueError: "ValueError: Invalid mode ('wr')".  

The interesting thing is that I don't receive any sort of error when the file is generated from the socket like so: `socket_file = socket.makefile('wrb')'.  According to the docs, makefile returns a file object like any other file, so shouldn't it fail in this case like any other file?

Comment: I'm not sure. The most logical thing to do would be to update your python interpreter to the most recent supported version in the 2.x series, which looks to be 2.7.6; on my machine. Also I'm not familiar with how Windows handles python libraries, or any platform specific issues that may arise from using Windows.