# ConfigParser - remove_section don't remove section

Tags: python, python-2.7, ini

I have tool, which intended to generate and display configurations (sections).

INI-file looks like:

```
...

[test]
MATH_DLL = 035f210e-6c06-4021-8857-0759409c4bb7
MATH_DLL_XML = 805fe0f0-2627-4ced-bac5-8725ef9839ef
ASSETMANAGER_API_DLL = 426d1824-628f-47ed-8539-4a0ed292b94e
...
```

What I want now - add option to remove section to "main" file:

```
...
parser_unity.add_argument('-x', '--remove', action='store', dest='unity_uuid_remove',
                          help='Remove configuration from uuids.ini. Must be called with config_name to delete')
...
```

And:

```
def handler_unity(action_list):
...
    if action_list.unity_uuid_remove:
        from lib.unity.uuidgen import UuuidManagment
        u = UuuidManagment(logger, RDS_BASEDIR)
        u.config_remove(action_list.unity_uuid_remove)
```

And class and method:

```
class UuuidManagment(object):

    """Class for data in uuids.ini file management"""

    def __init__(self, logger, rds_basedir):

        self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.config_file = os.path.join(rds_basedir, 'conf', 'unity', 'uuids.ini')
        self.config.read(self.config_file)
        self.configs = self.config.sections()

        self.logger = logger
        self.rds_basedir = rds_basedir

    ...

    def config_remove(self, config_name):

        """Remove config_name specified in argument from uuids.ini"""

        self.logger.logger.info('Remove %s' % config_name)

        print(self.config, self.configs, config_name)

        self.config.remove_section(config_name)

        with open(self.config_file, 'r+') as out:
            self.config.write(out)
```

But it's don't want to work.

Current configs:

```
d:\RDS\rdsmanager>RDSmanager.py unity -l                                                                                              
RDSmanager started at 09, Jul 2015 at 17:05:35                                                                                        
Running configlist                                                                                                                    

Currently avalable configurations:                                                                                                    

develop                                                                                                                               
debug                                                                                                                                 
qa                                                                                                                                    
version_1_0_2_staging                                                                                                                 
test
```

Remove it:

```
d:\RDS\rdsmanager>RDSmanager.py unity -x test                                                                                         
RDSmanager started at 09, Jul 2015 at 17:05:40                                                                                        
Remove test                                                                                                                           
(<lib.external.ConfigParser.ConfigParser instance at 0x02346580>, ['develop', 'debug', 'qa', 'version_1_0_2_staging', 'test'], 'test')
```

Check again:

```
d:\RDS\rdsmanager>RDSmanager.py unity -l                                                                                              
RDSmanager started at 09, Jul 2015 at 17:05:42                                                                                        
Running configlist                                                                                                                    

Currently avalable configurations:                                                                                                    

develop                                                                                                                               
debug                                                                                                                                 
qa                                                                                                                                    
version_1_0_2_staging                                                                                                                 
test
```

Comment: @Gall sorry, don't get it... Could you clarify, please?

Comment: What if you use ``w`` instead of ``r+`` to update the file?

Comment: @Gall Please, add it as answer :-) (just FYI - `'w+'` works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config_remove` you open the file in `r+` mode.

You should open it in write/truncate mode `w` to properly rewrite the file, as you can see in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open).

> 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists)

For more information, this question: [Confused by python file mode “w+”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w) is related to the actual purpose of the `+` variants.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to: `with open(self.config_file, 'w+') as out` - and now it's work. Stupid issue :-)

Comment: @setevoy I added a link to a question related to the ``+`` variants for more information on what is more appropriate to use.