# Receive data from server in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well, i want to receive some bytes from a client to a server in python. So I send some strings from client: OLA, 135 and A.

The code lines of server is:

```
while True:
    # Receive the data one byte at a time
    data = connection.recv(1)
    file = open("test.txt", "w")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    sys.stdout.write(data)
```

I want to write these strings sended by client in a txt file. But after I received all strings in the server I open the txt file created and there are nothing. What is wrong?

Comment: If file not found open in write mode, else open file in append mode. This looks like an infinite loop to me. When are you breaking out of the loop ?

Comment: The code continues with:

                if data:
                    # Send back in uppercase
                    connection.sendall(data.upper())
                else:
                    print('no more data, closing connection.')
                    break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, open file with `"w"` removes previous file.

`'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending;`

So using "a" to keep existing data.

```
while True:
    # Receive the data one byte at a time
    data = connection.recv(1)
    file = open("test.txt", "a") # change 'w' to 'a'
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    sys.stdout.write(data)
```

Reference : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Do you think that code: data = connection.recv(1) don't save the complete string received?

Comment: @Leonardo it basically rewrites the contents of your file since it is opened in 'w' mode! [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w) might help!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran It's working. Thank you very much. Can I request the created file from a web page?

Comment: @Leonardo do you wanna get html from url and save it as local file?

Comment: @ikicha I want to request with a web page the .txt file created by the communication with client and server. My web page was another client.