# python - keyword search program

Tags: python, keyword, file-search

Hey i writing a program that´s supposed to searches through .log files and find a keyword "Complete Respons". All found keywords should later be writen and saved in a new .txt file. I have now managed the program to search through one document at the time, but i have +50 documents of the same typ in one directory that i want to search through all at the same time and put all found keyword in the same .txt document. I could really use some help...!
Thanks

```
def read_log_file(filename, keyword):   #file

    saved_word = []  # Array
# read file
    with open(filename) as file_search:   #open search file
        file_search = file_search.readlines()   #read file
    for lines in file_search:    # every word is scaned
           if keyword in lines:   # extract the keyword
                saved_word.append(lines)    #store all found keywords in array
        # write in new file
    with open('CompleteResponse.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
        file_handler.write(f"{filename}\n")
        for i in range(len(saved_word)):
            file_handler.write(f"{saved_word[i]}")

    print('done') # completed

    print(len(saved_word)) # count found words

read_log_file(r'C:\Users\\Documents\read_log_files\test.log', 'Complete Response:')
```

Comment: Please detail the question: do you have problems? exceptions?

Comment: @fili: the answer given by @Shai will get you there. Just some comments on your code: `for lines in file_search` - why the plural? do `for line in file_search`, also don't get into the habit of `file_search = file_search.readlines()` as this changes the type of `file_search` and can lead to subtle bugs. lastly, `file_search` and `file_handler` are weird names. And as the log files get big, you might want to avoid reading them all in to an array and just process line by line....

Answer (score 3):

Open your output file `'CompleteResponse.txt'` in *append* mode, instead of *write*:

```
with open('CompleteResponse.txt', 'a') as file_handler:
```

Then call your function in a loop:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('C:\Users\\Documents\read_log_files\*.log'):
    read_log_file(filename, 'Complete Response:')
```

Should do the trick for you.

You can find a detailed list of file opening modes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566951/1714410).

---

PS,
If you intend to call this function several times, the output file `'CompleteResponse.txt'` will contain ALL results (concatenation of ALL outputs from ALL runs).
To avoid this, you might want to "reset" the file **before** processing all log files:

```
with open('CompleteResponse.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    pass # open with 'w' to "reset" the file.
```

Comment: @Shai Thanks you so much, it works exactlly how i wanted it to!