# python 3 permanently returns No such file or directory during writing

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, error-handling

It looks stupid but I can't handle this issue.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(cwd)
file_name = 'tes.txt'
with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('hhhh')
f.close()
```

when I start this simple code it always returns me

> with open(file_name, 'w+') as f: 
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'

On other computer the same code works well, as expected.

If I'm trying to address to file which already exists

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(cwd)
# print(os.listdir(cwd))
file_name = 'tether_full_data.txt'
with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('hhhh')
f.close()
```

it returns

> OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

I did a lot of search and tried a lot of ways. But with no success on this PC (only on this PC).

Windows 10 PRO, version 1709, OS Build 16299.19

Comment: That does not solve your problem, but you don't need the `f.close()` when you are using a context manager (`with`) to open the file.

Comment: And if you just want to write to the file, use only `w` instead of  `w+`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16212401/5276734 for all file modes.

Comment: And  your first error message mentions another file then your code.

Comment: You will get the second error [Errno 9] if  a Python file was closed from "the outside", i.e. not from the file object's close() method. As for it not working, did you try giving absolute path of the file?

Comment: @d_void cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(cwd)
print(cwd)
# print(os.listdir(cwd))
file_name = r'C:\Users\sergeysolod\OneDrive\ICO\tether_full_data.txt'
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write('hhhh')
f.close()         It returns the same OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: @bastelflp   Thanks for your willing to help! Actually I have been trying a lot of different options, 'w', 'w+', 'r', 'a'. Two different names of files mean that I tried to use two files to test. One of those tests was to try to create a new file. Next attempt was to write data (simple string) to file which already exists. \