# Text to Excel in Python overwrites existing data

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I have a small script, and I am trying to parse data from text file to Excel file instead of going till the counter which is till 166 it stops at 134 and then doesn't do anything. 
I have a file close operation also but it doesn't close the file and looks like the script continues to run. 
Any thoughts?  What am I doing wrong ?

```
path = ('C:\\Users\\40081\\PycharmProjects\\abcd')
#file_name = open('parsed_DUT1.txt', 'r')
file_name = 'parsed_DUT1.txt'
count=1


for line in file_name:
    inputfile = open(file_name)
    outputfile = open("parsed_DUT1" + '.xls', 'w+')
    while count < 166:
        for line in inputfile:
            text = "TestNum_" + str(count*1)
            if text in line :
                #data = text[text.find(" ")+1:].split()[0]
                outputfile.writelines(line)
                count = count+1
    inputfile.close()
    outputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [w+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566951/9364494)

> Opens a file for both writing and reading. Overwrites the existing
>   file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new
>   file for reading and writing.

You are opening the output file in `w+` mode, that overwrites it everytime. Try with

```
outputfile = open("parsed_DUT1" + '.xls', 'a') # 'a' opens a file for appending.
```

I also suggest you to deal with files with `with` statement:

```
with open(file_name) as inputfile, open("parsed_DUT1" + '.xls', 'a') as outputfile:
    # do stuff with input and output files
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.