# What does truncate mean in python file I/o?

Tags: python-3.x

I stumbled upon the post, which tells that **w+** can truncate a file, whereas **r+** file mode can not.

I am having difficulties understanding what **truncate** means and what **file.truncate()** does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)

Comment: The answers to the dupe are far more enlightening then your self answer - see if they clarify things for you and consider  closing this question.

Answer (score 2):

Differences between the modes described in the built-in
function [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

> Modes `w+` and `w+b` open and truncate the file. Modes `r+` and `r+b`
> open the file with no truncation.

Where truncate means to remove all bytes from the opened file, i.e. current position at `0` and current file size of `0` bytes.

---

`file.truncate()` as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=truncate#io.IOBase.truncate)

> Resize the stream to the given size in bytes (or the current position
> if size is not specified). The current stream position isn’t changed.
> This resizing can extend or reduce the current file size. In case of
> extension, the contents of the new file area depend on the platform
> (on most systems, additional bytes are zero-filled). The new file size
> is returned.

### Behaviour of `truncate()` depending on reading mode `r`, `r+`, `rb` or `rb+`

- ### r

  Raise an error: `io.UnsupportedOperation: truncate` as mode `r` only
  allows reading a stream.
- ### r+

  1. `truncate()` - not specifying `size`

     - `current position` is `0`:
       truncate the file to `0` bytes - behaves the same as using `w`
       or `w+`.
     - `current position` changed by using `read(n)` or at least
       once `readline()`:
       file size remains the same, truncate returns current size of file.
  2. `truncate(size)`

     - Independent from the `current position` truncates the file to
       the specified size. If `size` is greater than the original file
       size fill bytes until `size` with the `Null` character `\x00`.
- ### rb

  Behave the same as mode `r` and raises
  `io.UnsupportedOperation: truncate`.
- ### rb+

  Without specifying `size` truncate the file at the current position
  otherwise truncate file to given size. If necessary fill end of file
  with `Null` character `\x00` to fill additional bytes.

---

### `truncate()` behaves the same for writing modes `w`, `w+`, `wb` and `wb+`

As writing mode `w` will truncate the file on open, using
`truncate()` returns `0`.
If the file is still `0` bytes, `truncate(size)` can be used to define
the file size by filling additional bytes with `\x00`.

Answer (score -1):

In crude terms, **truncate** is about removal of the text from your file starting from the current position until the end of the file.

Assume a file has 5 lines:

```
file.readline() # reads the first line
file.truncate() # removes the lines 2 through 5.
file.readline() # returns '' since lines have been deleted
file.seek(0) # moves the cursor to the start of the file
file.readline() # reads the first line again
```

Comment: If this is intended to be a self-answered question - this isn't even a correct answer...

Comment: @JonClements you are always welcome to provide a better one and downvote anything you don't like