# Issue with appending to txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to to read and write to the same file. currently the data in `2289newsML.txt` exists as normal sentences but I want to append the file so it stores only tokenized versions of the same sentences.

I used the code below but even tho it prints out tokenized sentences it doesnt write them to the file.

```
from pathlib import Path
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

news_folder = Path("file\\path\\")
news_file = (news_folder / "2289newsML.txt")

f = open(news_file, 'r+')
data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    print(words)
    f.writelines(words)

f.close
```

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to write the tokenized words to the same file?

Comment: yes i have saved duplicate versions for this reason- in all fairness i wouldn't mind saving tokenized words to a new file in a different directory either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
with open("input.txt") as f1, open("output.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.writelines(("\n".join(word_tokenize(line)) for line in f1.readlines()))
```

Using `with` comprehension ensures file handle will be taken care of. So you do not need `f1.close()`

This program is writing to a different file.

Of course, you can do it this way too:

```
f = open(news_file)
 data = f.readlines()

file = open("output.txt", "w")


for line in data:
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    print(words)
    file.write('\n'.join(words))

f.close
file.close
```

Output.txt will have the tokenized words.

Comment: i get a  error:   file.write(words)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list.. i changed file.writelines too - it runs but nothing gets written to the file.

Comment: @TheBrownBatman, that is because the output from tokenize function is list. I have made the fix by converting list to string by using "join" method. Try now.

Comment: the output file is still showing up as blank txt file

Comment: And when execution reaches -> print(words), you see the words  printed, is that right?

Comment: yes `print(words)` has been working perfectly so far

Comment: Can you posted first few lines of your text file ? (2289newsML.txt)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPVStk1cXHSDyyEwJD12D8906nMbbdzq/view?usp=sharing
 the first line was too long by 426 characters so i am sharing the file with you. If you are uncomfortable clicking the link - i can pastethe first 2 lines in multiple comments

Comment: I used the same file and ran program locally. I can see it is working for me. Can you make sure you have write access to the place where you are creating output.txt? If  you are on Linux/MacOs, try creating the file in /tmp

Comment: I am admin on Windows 10  so i should have access - `output_dir = Path ("output\\path\\")
output_file = (output_dir / "2289newsML.txt")` is something i added to replace `output.txt, "w"` but this isnt a issue as it creates the file in the folder but does not write anything to it. I also tried to create the file in the same dir as the original but that has the same result.

Comment: weird thing - the first code of 2 lines you posted creates the file AND write it BUT without no tokenization in the new file.

Comment: I tried the second method assuming you will prefer that. Let me modify first method then.

Comment: Also, for the second method creating empty file, can you make sure file.close() is called? (print statements should be enough.) I assume the file is not closed properly.

Comment: @TheBrownBatman , I have modified the first method and tested it. Now every word is printed on new line. Can you try now?

Comment: The above `print` was being called. and using the modified first code words do get printed on a new line of a new file. thanks for your help, Ill figure out the rest from here :)

Comment: Great! What I meant was to add these print lines. print("before calling file close") ; file.close(); print("after file close"). I suspect in the second method the file was not closed (That is the only thing I can think of). In any case always prefer the first way to read/write files as it handles close of files automatically for you.

Comment: yea i added something similar to those print statements ill see why no2 wasnt working for me - seems weird it shouldnt

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to to read and write to the same file. currently the data
>   in 2289newsML.txt exists as normal sentences but I want to append the
>   file...

Because you are opening file in `r+` mode.

`'r+'` Open for reading and writing.  **The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file**.

If you want to append new text at the end of file consider opening file in `a+` mode.

Read more about **[open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)**

Read more about **[file modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16212401/1246764)**

Comment: i tried a+ aswell but that didnt have any result - it seemed to not trigger the `for` loop so i stuck with r+