# Python write and read is not working with same file Descriptor

Tags: python, file, file-descriptor

I'm using the below code to write to file and read the content which i have write. 
However, it is giving me empty content when i read it.

```
text = 'Blah1'

with open('my_file.txt', 'r+') as file:
    file.write(text)
    print 'Content created.\n'
    print 'Now reading from file.\n'
    Content = file.read()
    print 'Content is : ' + Content
```

I think i'm missing something or misunderstood something. Any explain on this why this wont work would be appreciate.

PS: It work if i use different file descriptors.

Comment: You should replace cursor to the beginning of the file. `file.seek(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reposition the current read/write position with `seek` as described here [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)