# CSV file only writes 256 lines in a nested loop

Tags: python, csv

I have 3 nested loops: one that goes through 5 images, one that goes through the 3 RGB channels of each image, and finally, one that creates a histogram of each image. I want to write the histogram of each image in a CSV file using the code below. However, instead of repeating 256 times for each channel, it only prints the first 256, then stops working. This method works fine with the `print()` function. Why doesn't it go through each with my CSV file then?

```
for image in images:
img = cv2.imread("%s%s" % (path, image))  # Load the image
channels = cv2.split(img)  # Set the image channels
colors = ("b", "g", "r")  # Initialize tuple
plt.figure()
plt.title("Color Histogram")
plt.xlabel("RGB Bins")
plt.ylabel("Number of Pixels")

for (i, col) in zip(channels, colors):  # Loop over the image channels
    hist = cv2.calcHist([i], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])  # Create a histogram for current channel
    plt.plot(hist, color=col)  # Plot the histogram
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
    hist = hist.astype(int)
    print(hist)
    with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerows(hist)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. We can't tell what's included in the `for image in images:` loop.

Comment: Every time you open `mycsv.csv` in `w` mode it removes the previous contents. You should either open the file once before all the loops, or open it in `a` mode to append.

Comment: So you should be getting the *last* 256, not the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a file with "w" mode [erases it's contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w). You should use "a" to append, or "a+" if you want to both append and read the file. The pointer will be in all cases put at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

"Every time you open mycsv.csv in w mode it removes the previous contents. You should either open the file once before all the loops, or open it in a mode to append. – Barmar"

This worked thanks a lot. I'm new to SOF, so I don't know how to flag it as a working answer. Anyways, the fixed code is:

...
with open('mycsv.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
...