# writing file before anything else in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, turtle-graphics

I have a definition where it will write a file and put all the characters and their occurrences and then sorts it and I run into this error where one of my lines of code can't do anything because nothing has been written to the file yet, I put the file write  before this and it doesn't write unless I comment out the section that sorts it after

```
  file = open("leaderboard.txt", "w+")

  def always_write_the_file(x):
    while x < len(collected_people):
      file.write("%s %s\n" % (collected_people[x], collected_characters.count(collected_people[x])))
      x = x + 1
  
  always_write_the_file(x)

  x = 0

  with open("leaderboard.txt") as  f:
    leaderboard = f.read().splitlines()

  while x < len(collected_people):
    character_count_turtle.penup()
    character_count_turtle.goto(non_depth, depth)
    character_count_turtle.pendown()
    
    sorted_leaderboard = sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)[-1]))

    
    character_count_turtle.write("%s" % (sorted_leaderboard[x]), font=("arial", int(leaderboard_size), "normal"))

    depth = depth - (int(leaderboard_size) + 2)
    x = x + 1
```

the error I get is

[image: error]

probably because nothing has been written to the file...

[image: nothing in leaderboard.txt]

there for sure is stuff written here though

[image: stuff written there]

Comment: Please be precise about what's wrong, "I run into this error where one of my lines of code can't do anything because nothing has been written to the file yet" *What error*? Provide the full error message including the stack trace. Please always provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your edit is great in that it conveys more information, but note that 1) Uploading images of error messages isn't great. Other users won't be able to search for the error message. Instead, you can quote it or format it as code. 2) You can just say `leaderboard.txt` is empty, and that `character_data.txt` has text.

Comment: Note as well that when you open a file, you must call `f.close()` or you will not be able to see what you have written to it. The `with open ... as f:` statement implicitly closes the file when the `with` statement ends. Also note that you probably mean to write `open("leaderboard.txt", 'r')` at the with statement in your code, where you don't specify the open mode. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566951/11659881) the default mode is to read binary (`rb`), which you probably don't want.

Comment: ah I see this seems to fix it, thank you!

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the open mode when calling the `open()` function:

```
  with open("leaderboard.txt", "r") as  f:
    leaderboard = f.read().splitlines()
```

Note that in this function:

```
  def always_write_the_file(x):
    while x < len(collected_people):
      file.write("%s %s\n" % (collected_people[x], collected_characters.count(collected_people[x])))
      x = x + 1
```

Instead of a `while` loop, you can use a `for` loop:

```
  def always_write_the_file(x_start):
    for x in range(x_start, len(collected_people)):
      file.write("%s %s\n" % (collected_people[x], collected_characters.count(collected_people[x])))
```