# Is there any method to append the value to the list in JSON file (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x

My exercise idea is to append new value from the input prompt to the list. Instead of adding new value, my list in JSON file always give the newly inputted value.

```
    import json

    file = 'database.json'

    namelist = []
    name = input("Enter your name:\n")

    with open(file, 'w') as file_object:
        namelist.append(name)
        json.dump(namelist, file_object)
```

Comment: [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w) may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('database.json', "r+") as file_object:
    data = json.load(file)
    # data.update(your_dict) or data.append(new_data)
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.