# Attempting to write to file spits out nothing

Tags: python, file

When attempting to read a file in python it seems to print out just a space instead of "Test Message" here's my code:

```
contents = "Test Message"

def readAndWritetofile():
    with open("file.txt", 'w+') as file:
        file.write(contents)
        print(file.read())

    
    
readAndWritetofile()
```

Comment: ```file.seek(0)```- before ```print(file.read())```

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot

```
file.seek(0)
```

before line 6

Answer (score 1):

After the write the file pointer is at the end of the file. You can seek back to the start or reopen.

```
contents = "Test Message"

def readAndWritetofile():
    with open("file.txt", 'w+') as file:
        file.write(contents)
        file.seek(0)
        print(file.read())

readAndWritetofile()
```

or

```
contents = "Test Message"

def readAndWritetofile():
    with open("file.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(contents)
        # exit the with closes the file
    with open("file.txt") as file:
        print(file.read())

readAndWritetofile()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `file.seek(0)`. If you forget this, the `file.read()` call will try to read from the end of the file, and will return an empty string.

Currently, the pointer is at the end of the file. `file.seek(0)`moves it to the start of the file.

```
contents = "Test Message"

def readAndWritetofile():
    with open("file.txt", 'w+') as file:
        file.write(contents)
        file.seek(0)
        print(file.read())

readAndWritetofile()
```