# How to save changes made to a list in Python so it updates after rerunning the script?

Tags: python, list

So I know the .append function adds elements to a list. But that only works as long as the script is running. If I rerun the file, the list is back to its previous state with no changes made. Is there a way to save the changes?

Comment: You could write it to a file and then read it. File I/O is a standard way to maintain state between runs.

Comment: Either save it to a database or a text file, or change the python code as you run it

Answer (score 0):

You can save the list to a file after everything is done:

Here for `a+` mode:
All [file handling modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w) <---Here

> `a+`: Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist.

```
with open('test_file','a+') as file:
   lst=[...]
   ....
   file.write(lst)
```