# Selenium keeps on over-writing the same row in the .csv file while scraping data from web

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to scrape data from a news website using selenium in Jupyter. The scraper works fine and gets all the elements but while writing them to a .csv file it keeps on overwriting the first row.

Below is the code to write the header row of the file.

```
with open('news_articles.csv', 'w')as file:
    file.write("Date; Headline \n")
```

The following code scrapes the desired elements from the webpages.

```
for year in range(2011,2013):
    
    driver.get('http://www.sharechat.co.nz/news-archive.html?year='+str(year)) # To open year page
    time.sleep(4)
    try:
        ad= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ns-ek2m2-e-20"]/span')
        ad.click()
    except:
        pass
    
    for i in range(14,16):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='col-md-8 content']/a["+str(i)+"]")))) # To open headline
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            ad= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ns-ek2m2-e-20"]/span')
            ad.click()
        except:
            pass
            
        headline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@class='col-md-8 content']/h1")
        date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='small']")
        
        
        #print(date.text)
        #print(headline.text)
        
        
        article = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='contentarticle']/p")
        noOfElements = len(article)
        for p in range(noOfElements-3):
            print(article[p].text)
```

Now, when I try to write the scraped elements into the same file but in the following rows, the same row keeps on getting over-written.

```
        with open('news_articles.csv', 'w')as file:
            file.write(date.text + "; " + headline.text + "\n")
```

Comment: Use `with open('news_articles.csv', 'a')as file:` `w` stands for write. `a` stands for append. so write creates a new file each time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)