# Python file mode flag ordering

Tags: python, filesystems

Is there a documented ordering to the characters in an open file's `.mode` in python?

I'm interested in safely determining the mode of a file-like object I'm receiving as a parameter. Is there a *documented* list of all possible modes of an *open* file? I could create an exhaustive list of all permutations of the flags that [`open(, mode=...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) takes, but some will be nonsensical (`ax`).

I'm more interested in the possible values of the mode attribute of a file like object - and *especially* the order that I can expect those flags to appear. For instance here's 4 different ways to open a file that all create a file-like object in `rb+` mode.

```py
In [1]: with open('/tmp/foo', 'r+b') as foo:
   ...:     print(foo.mode)
   ...: 
rb+

In [2]: with open('/tmp/foo', 'rb+') as foo:
   ...:     print(foo.mode)
   ...: 
rb+

In [3]: with open('/tmp/foo', 'br+') as foo:
   ...:     print(foo.mode)
   ...: 
rb+

In [4]: with open('/tmp/foo', 'bw+') as foo:
   ...:     print(foo.mode)
   ...: 
rb+
```

Essentially my question is if there is any documented determinism to the order of the file-mode characters (incl. across platforms)? It's clearly not just sorted in alphanumeric order.

This question ([Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)) is the closest answer I could find, but there's no references, and no explanation of how I can trust that python will never return any of the equivalent modes above when calling `<file>.mode` (`br+`, `r+b`, `w+b`, `wb+` for what is reported as `rb+` on my system).

Comment: Chances that it's inspired by the C file-opening mode. Just type in `man fopen` in a Unix/Linux shell and you'll see the difference between `r+` and `w+` according to the C language. Nothing sure but the behavior could be the same.
Maybe nothing more in my comment than [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w).
But needs to be said.